# Orange wont allow me to set target for corpus

Tags: orange

I would like to do a linear regression on an excel file. I have descriptions in one column and category in the other.

I need to be able to set the target to do a linear regression. However, Orange does not allow me to set target variable the way it would when I use the file module. The problem with opening the data as file is that I will not be able to use bag of words (since thats only for corpus).

When I do use Corpus, it automatically detects all columns as meta.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a work around?

Comment: You can use the 'Select Columns'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do something like this? (or am I missing something?)

[image]